# Where are django's annotated fields stored on the model instance?

Tags: django, django-models, django-aggregation

I am doing this:

```
p = MyModel.objects.filter(user__username="me").annotate(friend_count=Count(friends))
```

when I look at:

```
p[0]._meta.get_all_field_names()
```

It returns everything defined on the model but not the annotated field 'friend_count'

Is there a function I can use to see all the annotated fields of a particular model instance?

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
p.query.annotations.keys()
```

It will give the list of all annotated fields.

Answer (score 0):

annotations are just stored as plain instance attributes (just like the values for the ORM fields FWIW). You can use `dir(my_model_instance)` to see all the attributes (class and instance ones) names, or `my_model_instance.__dict__.keys()` for the plain instance attributes only.